# How to read and output the XML within an SPFile?

Tags: development, asp.net, xml

I have this line of code that retrieves an XML file and saves it as an SPFile object

```
SPFile XMLFile = SPContext.Current.Web.GetFile("C:\\Users\\maleem\\Documents\\XMLTest.xml");
```

I want to get the XML/Text within it and output it to a literal, I tried

```
StreamReader  reader = new StreamReader(XMLFile.OpenBinaryStream());
```

...and a few variants but its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used code like this successfully

```
SPFolder fldr = web.Folders[strLibraryUrl];
SPFile file = fldr.Files[XMLFileUrl];
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
byte[] bites = file.OpenBinary();
Stream strm = new MemoryStream(bites);
xmlDoc.Load(strm);

// Now you can select nodes, loop, or whatever
XmlNodeList nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("Files/File");
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    // Your logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet, [from here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19753.read-xml-file-from-document-library-all-sharepoint-version.aspx):

```
string site = "http://servername/sites/TestSite";     
using(SPSite spsite = new SPSite(site))
{

 using(SPWeb spweb = spsite.OpenWeb())              
 {

   SPFile file = spweb.GetFile(strFileURL);

   StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenBinaryStream());
   XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(reader.ReadToEnd());
   xDoc = xdoc.ToXmlDocument();
   reader.Close()
}}
```

Does it give you an error or what is the outcome?

OR, modified from comment in same link:

```
string strFileURL = "SiteAssets/SiteNavigation/AMSNav.xml";

string xmlString = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.GetFileAsString(strFileURL);
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
```